# Can i use my laptop to stream video files on multiple android devices?

Tags: windows-10, video-streaming, sharing

Let's start from the beginning, i have a laptop (windows 10) in which i have saved a lot of video files around 100 GB, i want to share those files with my sister such  that she can connect her android phone to my pc and can stream those videos on her phone and at the same time i also can watch those lectures on the laptop but i want to give her read-only access so that she cannot delete any of those files ?

Is there a way to do the same or nearly the same ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible solutions. The first that came to my mind is using VLC (video lan client) app like described [here](https://www.vlchelp.com/android-complete-guide/) to access samba served files from your pc with what ever rights you want to give.
1. click on the files/folder with a right click and use share files to set up the share rights and f.e. a password.
2. download the vlc app on your sisters phone and tap on "local network" to access the samba folder share you shared on 1. (You both should be connected to the same network - boom - she can see the videos while you do stuff on your computer.

---

A second solution could be setting up an apache server with php support like described [here](https://miloserdov.org/?p=55) or [here](https://www.znetlive.com/blog/how-to-install-apache-php-and-mysql-on-windows-10-machine/) for example.
Than create an `index.php` file containing this:

```php
    <?php
      if ($handle = opendir('video/.')) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
          if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            $thelist .= '<li><a href="video/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';
          }
        }
        closedir($handle);
      }
    ?>
    <h1>List of files in /Downloads/Video/:</h1>
    <ul><?php echo $thelist; ?></ul>
```

This shows all files in a /video folder in `/srv/http/` or where ever you got your homepage files in - maybe `C:\dev\www\` .

Now you can take your sisters phone, type in the [IP of your computer](https://idoc.vsb.cz/xwiki/bin/view/tuonet/sit-nastaveni/ip-adresa/ip-win10-cmd/?xpage=print&language=en) *(f.e. 192.168.1.14 with opening cmd and type in `ipconfig /all` like described [here](https://idoc.vsb.cz/xwiki/bin/view/tuonet/sit-nastaveni/ip-adresa/ip-win10-cmd/?xpage=print&language=en))* in the firefox app address line and it should show all your video files and you should be able to actually watch the video files directly by clicking on it - at least with the firefox mobile app.

She cannot delete any of the files if you restrict the access with samba (first method) and can't delete any files with the second method too. She can download files if she can read them - keep that in mind.

I hope that helped and answered your question :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably easiest way is to synchronize your videos to a cloud (OneDrive, Google drive, dropbox...) and your sister can stream them from there.

Answer (score 0):

For this amount of data I would recommend a personal media server. Plex is my preference, easy to set up and has clients for virtually any platform. Server can run on various NAS too, without the need to have a PC.